# Sitecore: FAQ creation facility

Tags: sitecore

In sitecore one can use Web Forms for Marketers to create Forms. Is there a standard facility to create FAQ?

Comment: Please clarify your question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This would be fairly trivial functionality to build out using standard Sitecore templates/sublayouts/etc. It would be content, and thus doesn't need a plugin or module.